# Calculate field interactively in ArcGIS ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, modelbuilder

I'm working on a closest facility analysis using ArcGIS ModelBuilder and want to enable the user to add locations interactively (i.e. typing the coordinates, not using any table or source layer).

I created a point feature class with two fields (X, Y) in ModelBuilder and added a new row -a new point- using a small Python script, so I only need to create something that allows the user to type the coordinates of the point and copy them to the (X, Y) fields of the feature class.

I have tried it with Create Variable (either Point or Double) + Collect Values + Append, but it does not work because the outputs of Collect Values are not recognised as valid inputs in Append.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Is the model creating one point feature each time it is run?

Comment: As it is designed now, yes. Maybe I will modify that in the end, but my concern now is how to fill in the X (Add Field) and Y (Add Field (2)) fields of the point I create with Add Row.

Comment: Have not tested but you should be able to create a variable for both those parameters and use in-line variable substitution method within Calculate Field tool to write the values to the defined fields.  If in the future you move to many features I would recommend converting the model to a python script tool and using arcpy da update cursor to write the values.

Comment: Many thanks artwork21, that makes sense. I have tried it for X creating a variable named X_Value (double, same type that the field) and typing %X_Value% in Expression in Calculate Field, but it does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, make sure your variables and the destination calculated fields are of the same data type (Double to Double or String to String...etc) (if string your in-line variable will need double quotes surround the percent symbols):

[image]

and...

[image]